# Изменить вывод стандартных сообщений от wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Может сталкивался кто. Как можно изменить стандартное поведение вывода сообщений от wp? хотелось бы вообще в попапе все это делать. 
Сейчас работает так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Создавайте свой обработкич и через wp_insert_comment добавляйте комментраий)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть два способа вывести своё сообщение об ошибке.

1. Создайте файл `/wp-content/php-error.php`. Он будет вызван во время возникновения ошибки, его вывод вы увидите на экране.
2. Добавьте следующий код в `functions.php`. Ваше сообщение появится на экране.

```
function wp_die_handler_func( $message, $title, $args ) {
    echo 'Моё сообщение об ошибке';
}

function wp_die_handler_name( $name ) {
    return 'wp_die_handler_func';
}
add_filter( 'wp_die_handler', 'wp_die_handler_name' );
```

Да, вы можете оформить ваше сообщение об ошибке в виде всплывающего окна (popup). Но продолжить выполнение кода после ошибок типа `E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_USER_ERROR, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR` невозможно.

Comment: спасибо. теперь хотя бы знаю в каком направление копать

Comment: Если ответ принят, его стоит отметить галочкой внизу. Если информация в ответе полезна, можно нажать на стрелку вверх. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.